# C# Win App Remote access to sql databse in server

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a windows Form application using c# which actually connects to MySQL database. I've created a c# class which actually connects to my sql and it's working fine with local wamp server. I am trying to put the database in the server and access it remotely within the network. There is also a xamp server in the server 2003, I put the database in it but I cannot access it remotely. I've also tried mysql workbench but also the same thing. I am very new to this, Can anyone help me?

I have the following:

//----{ conn.txt }-----

```
      hostname:192.168.11.10
      username:root
      password:
      database:contact_list
```

//----{ filePath.cs }----

```
    class filePath
    {
       private string connectionFilePath;
       public filePath()
       {
         this.connectionFilePath = "";
       }
       public string get()
       {
         connectionFilePath = "conn/config.txt";
         return this.connectionFilePath;
       }
    }
```

//----{ dbBroker.cs }-----

```
  class dbBroker
  {
    private string dbHostname;
    private string dbUsername;
    private string dbPassword;
    private string dbname;
    private string connectionString;
    private filePath connFilePath;
    public int SUCCCESS = 0;
    private MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
    private MySqlCommand commmand = new MySqlCommand();
    private MySqlDataAdapter adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    private DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    public dbBroker()
    {
        this.dbHostname = "";
        this.dbUsername = "";
        this.dbPassword = "";
        this.dbname = "";
        this.connectionString = "";
        this.connFilePath = new filePath();
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(this.connFilePath.get()))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new                                      System.IO.StreamReader(this.connFilePath.get());
            string[] attributes = new string[4];
            string l;
            string[] wrds;
            int i = 0;
            while ((l = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                wrds = l.Split(':');
                attributes[i++] = wrds[1];
            }
            this.dbHostname = attributes[0];
            this.dbUsername = attributes[1];
            this.dbPassword = attributes[2];
            this.dbname = attributes[3];
            file.Close();
        }
    }
    public void setHostname(string hostnameStr)
    {
        this.dbHostname = hostnameStr;
    }
    public void setUsername(string usernameStr)
    {
        this.dbUsername = usernameStr;
    }
    public void setPassword(string passStr)
    {
        this.dbPassword = passStr;
    }
    public void setDbName(string dbNameStr)
    {
        this.dbname = dbNameStr;
    }

    public string getHostname()
    {
        return this.dbHostname;
    }
    public string getUsername()
    {
        return this.dbUsername;
    }
    public string getPassword()
    {
        return this.dbPassword;
    }
    public string getDbName()
    {
        return this.dbname;
    }
    public void setConnectionString()
    {
        this.connectionString = "Server=" + this.dbHostname + ";Database=" + this.dbname + ";Uid=" + this.dbUsername + ";Pwd=" + this.dbPassword;
    }
    public string getConnectionString()
    {
        return this.connectionString;
    }
    public int connect()
    {
        try
        {
            this.setConnectionString();
            this.conn.ConnectionString = this.getConnectionString();
            this.conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 1;

        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                this.conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public int executeQuery(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            commmand.Connection = this.conn;
            commmand.CommandText = query;
            adapt.SelectCommand = commmand;
            adapt.Fill(ds);


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public DataSet getDs()
    {
        return this.ds;
    }
    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return this.conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What result is occurring?  ummm, 'conn.txt' vs 'conn/config.txt'

Comment: Can you connect using the same connection string in a mysql client/administrator tool?

Comment: Before worrying about your code, I would suggest getting it working from workbench. Verify on the database server you have a user created, that they have permissions from the hostmask you'll be connecting from and that the user has permissions to the database(s) you want to work with.

Comment: The code is working fine with localhost. There's nothing wrong when I run the app locally with wamp server. My question is how can I connect to remotely using the same database, I've tried to use Ip address of the server as hostname (conn.txt) but my app cannot connect to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure the root user can login remotely via mysql.

This, just by the way, is a horrible idea, you should create a mysql user with priveleges needed and use that instead.